# Creating new column with decrementing and incrementing a date column by month

Tags: python, pyspark

I need help with one of my situation. There is a dataset where date column is of the format 'YYYYMM' and datatype is integer. Example is shown below :

[image: Input Dataset]

[image: Output Dataset]

Can someone please help me create output dataset from input dataset. I tried doing it but my method turned out to be expensive timewise. I need a solution that helps me get the desired output quickly as this has to be run on large dataset.

Increment column is created by fixing '201908' in 1st observation and decrementing the month value by 1 henceforth. Decrement column is created by decrementing the month of Date by 1 henceforth.

Answer (score 0):

Use window **row_number()** function to get the **row_number** values associated to each row and use **add_months** function to get increment and decrement column values.

**`Example:`**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import *
w=Window.orderBy(monotonically_increasing_id())

df.withColumn("tmp_rn",row_number().over(w)-1).\
withColumn("tmp",add_months(to_date(col("Date").cast("string"),"yyyyMM"),-1)).\
withColumn("Decrement",expr("date_format(add_months(tmp,-(tmp_rn)),'yyyyMM')")).\
withColumn("tmp2",to_date(lit("201908").cast("string"),"yyyyMM")).\
withColumn("Increment",expr("date_format(add_months(tmp2,-(tmp_rn)),'yyyyMM')")).\
drop(*["tmp_rn","tmp","tmp2"]).\
show()

#+---+------+---------+---------+
#| id|  date|Decrement|Increment|
#+---+------+---------+---------+
#|  1|201706|   201705|   201908|
#|  1|201706|   201704|   201907|
#|  1|201706|   201703|   201906|
#|  1|201706|   201702|   201905|
#|  1|201706|   201701|   201904|
#|  1|201706|   201612|   201903|
#|  1|201706|   201611|   201902|
#|  1|201706|   201610|   201901|
#|  1|201706|   201609|   201812|
#|  1|201706|   201608|   201811|
#|  1|201706|   201607|   201810|
#|  1|201706|   201606|   201809|
#+---+------+---------+---------+
```